# Generic method to get data from any table using ORMlite

Tags: java, database, sqlite, dao

I Am trying to create method that can get all the data from any table from SQLite using ormlite and Dao class, I do not know which values  set in Dao , the code looks like:

```
public <T> List<T> getAllRecords(Class<T> klass){
    String databaseUrl = "jdbc:sqlite:c:\\Users\\workspace\\my_sqlite";
    SQLiteDBLayer sQLiteDBLayer = new SQLiteDBLayer(SQLiteDBLayer.ConnectionType.READER);
    ConnectionSource connectionSource = null;
    try {
        connectionSource = new JdbcConnectionSource(databaseUrl);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Dao<???, String> transfor = null ; //???? is where I'm stuck
    List<T> results;
    try {
        transfor =DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource,????);//And Here also
        results= (List<T>) transfor.queryForAll();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

```
 Dao<T, String> transfor = null ; //solve 
    List<T> results;
    try {
        transfor =DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource,klass);//Solve
        results= (List<T>) transfor.queryForAll();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```